# Stretchable Images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uibutton, stretching

In reference to: [iPhone stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth only makes "D"s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924408/iphone-stretchableimagewithleftcapwidth-only-makes-ds)

I have an image of a button of size `13x30`. I want to stretch the image to fill the button which will be of size `45x30`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
UIImage *shareImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_red"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:16.0f topCapHeight:0.0];
UIButton *shareButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 46.0f, 30.0f)];
etc....
```

The image I get is quite off. I am getting the image in its real size, with some sort of a lighter shadow behind it as shown in the image [image: button].

Why is this happening? I don't understand at all. I have the stretchable logic correct and I've followed what everyone is saying in tutorials/posts.

If I get some assistance I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your left cap width is wrong? If your first image is only 13 pixels wide, how can the left cap be 16?

The left cap is the width on the original image that stays unstretched

Comment: Okay I've changed it to 13. Still the same issue. My button's frame is set to 46 x 30 as before.

Comment: Why did the answer by @user1447414 get accepted? We had no idea where you wanted to cut your image. He just suggests the center and incorrectly too (it should be 6 on the left, copy the center pixel, 6 on the right). Please read the Apple docs about this.

Comment: Paul, I accepted it because it worked. I read the Apple docs a lot about it. It was all nonsense. My image is 13px wide. I want to stretch it to 46 wide. I **still** have no idea why 6 was correct. To do so, I need to stretch the left side by 16px and the right side by 16px. 16.5 + 16.5 + 13 = 46! So how the hell do you stretch the left side by `6` and it works? If you answer this I will give you the correct answer.

Comment: That isn't how it works. You have a 13px image and you want to have the middle pixel stretched so that the final image is 46 pixels wide. So 13px-1(middle)px = 12px. The cap is on both sides, so 12px/2 = 6px. In fact your final image can be any size and the image will stretch the middle pixel (actually just copy the middle row of pixels into each required slot) to match the frame. ie: When you do the calculation, forget about the final size - that is what the stretch is for). You should also note that this method is deprecated in iOS 5.0

Comment: I just found a diagram of it: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/stretchable.png

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Paul's answer,

You want to make sure that you leave some space for stretching, so zoom in using Photoshop or something similar and decide what left pixels are absolutely required.

See this: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/08/stretchable-images-and-buttons/

Comment: I've seen this. Did what Paul recommended and it still does not work. In fact, its still the same exact problem.

Comment: Don't change it to 13 as you said above^, it needs to be 0<X<13

Answer (score 0):

LeftCapWidth should be 6.5;

```
UIImage *shareImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_red"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:6.5 topCapHeight:0.0];
UIButton *shareButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 46.0f, 30.0f)];
```